# How to resolder a broken connection for an LCD component

Tags: pcb, soldering

I'm new to electronics and I would like to learn how to attempt to repair a board like this.  As you can see in the image, it looks like someone has attempted this repair before, but the right connection has simply broken off.

I had the newbie intuition that I could just resolder this back on. Could anyone advise if this is a good option repairing this board?  Perhaps just applying a blob of solder?  Is there a more professional way?

[image]

Comment: I'd solder a, appropriate thickness, piece of wire on top of it to bridge the gap. Only using solder to bridge the gap will make it much more rigid and prone to breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're completely new to soldering, this isn't the best situation for your first attempt. But if you're feeling brave, here's what I'd do:

1. Clean off the old solder, and broken-off fragment of the lead, from the large pad on the PCB. To do this, apply some flux, heat the pad, and when the solder is liquefied, use a tweezers to pull off the old foil strap. If you have solder wick, that can help remove the old solder, but if not, some stranded wire can do the job. You don't have to get all the solder off, but try not to leave a large blob there.
2. Get some stranded wire (24 gauge or so), strip 1/2 inch insulation off the end, and solder the end onto the large pad. Use fresh solder, and flux. You're doing this end of the repair first because it requires more heat and won't come unsoldered as easily when you do the smaller end.
3. Now cut the stranded wire, leaving enough to bend downward to reach and contact the small strap coming from the smaller board. The wire needs to be in contact with the strap during the soldering operation. A small hemostat or alligator clip could help, but you probably don't have those, in which case you could even wrap a single loose strand of wire around to hold them together. Then use flux and solder to make the connection.

Good luck!

Comment: I would use a piece of solder wick braid as a conveniently pre-fluxed jumper in this case. Easier than stripping and tinning a wire.

Comment: @vofa has a good idea, just be careful not to use so much solder that it wicks so far into the braid that it stiffens it completely, because you want some flexibility there.

Comment: Also, be very quick with the second connection. Start by applying solder to the flat conductor which is sticking up from the lower board. Then make sure the wire has been tinned and has solder already on it. Then press the two together and apply heat just long enough to make a connection. If you apply too much heat, that tab on the lower piece may desolder, and it will stick to your iron via surface tension.